# SAS: create parameter that can look x months back

Tags: parameters, sas, sas-macro

I've been looking for a way to create a variable that can let me run a proc sql select a table for a specific 10 months looking back. the parameter should have the format of YYYYMM.

so e.g. &YYYYMM =  202102
this will allow me to run the proc sql select data from 202005 until 202101.

Any help would be so very much appreciated!!
Thanks very much!!

Comment: have you tried anything yet? here's an idea -- you can create a date using the yyyymm macro variable and store that in another macro variable. use the second variable and subtract 10 months using `intnx()`. quick tip - all of this can be done within macros... see `%sysfunc()`

Comment: i have tried to create temp table to do the months in scope but i guess it's not really necessary if everything can be done within macros. only i'm new to sas so i don't know much on how to code the macros yet. any help with elaborating your idea in code i think would be very very helpful in this regard!

Comment: Show what code you want to generate.  You cannot write a program (macro) to generate something if you don't know what you want to generate.

Comment: data months_in_scope;
do i = 1 to 10;
nr = i; 

yyyymm = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-1),yymmn6);
output;
end;

format yyyymm yymmn6.;
drop i;
run;

but this doesnt result i the yyyymm desired. the yyyymm that i would want to see is yyyymm of month of today -1 and going back 10 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make a dataset with one observation per date?  Do you want to make a DATE variable or CHARACTER variable? Or perhaps a numeric variable with those digit strings as numbers instead of actual date values?

```
%let end_month=202102;

data want;
  do offset=-9 to -1 ;
    date = intnx('month',input("&end_month",yymmn6.),offset);
    string=put(date,yymmn6.);
    number=input(string,6.);
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if you input 202102 then you want all the dates before 01.02.2021. Try the following:

```
/*Example dataset with dates*/
Data have(drop=x);
date = '01jan2020'd;
do x = 0 to 730;
    date = date + 1;
    output;
end;
Format date date9.;
Run;

/*Your variable in format YYYYMM*/
%Let date = 202102;

/*Convert to your variable SAS date */
Data _null_;
Format date_new date9.;
date_new = input("&date" !! "01",yymmdd8.);
Call symputx('date_new',date_new);
Run;
%put &date_new;

/*Select required date ranges from the have dataset*/
Proc sql;
Create table want as
Select * 
From have
Where intnx('month',&date_new,-10,'S') <= date < &date_new;
Quit;

/*Check results*/
Proc sql;
Select min(date) format=date9.
      ,max(date) format=date9.
From want;
Quit;
```

Comment: thanks a lot Serge! this indeed helps however what I'm trying to achieve is simply a table with list of yyyyymm going back 10 months from now. so as we're now in 202112, i would want my table to show all the yyyymm's from 202102 - 202111. but i guess perhaps i can improvise from your solution so thanks very much again!!!